# Quick check of closure under multiplication.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be an abelian group. Let $H = \{x \in G: x = x^{-1}\}$. Prove that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

The identity and inverse are trivial to show. I just want to check if I understand how to show closure under multiplication. Basically, we have to multiply two arbitrary elements in $H$ in such a way that the result abides by the given property in $H$.

Let $x, y \in H.$

$xy = yx $ since $H$ is abelian.

$= y^{-1} x^{-1} = (xy)^{-1}.$

So we have $xy = (xy)^{-1}$ just as prescribed by $H$.

Is that correct?

Comment: Is $x'$ in the definition of $H$ a fixed element of $G$ or is it a typo and you actually meant $x^{-1}$?

Comment: @ bharb, $x' = x^{-1}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the proof for closure under multiplication is correct, but for $H$ to be a subgroup other conditions need to be verified:

1. Closure under multiplication: 
    $x,y \in H \implies x*y\in H$
2. Closure under inversion:
    $x \in H \implies x^{-1} \in H$
3. Identity:
    $e \in H$

A quick way to check these three conditions in one simple passage is using this **[theorem](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test)**:

> If $G$ is a group and $H$ is a subset of $G$, then $H$ is a subgroup if and only if $x,y \in H \implies x*y^{-1}\in H$

Answer (score 2):

A conceptual way of doing this consists in noting that the map
$$
\varphi : G \to G \qquad x \mapsto x^{2}
$$
is a group homomorphism, as $G$ is abelian.

Now $H$ is the kernel of $\varphi$ (as $x = x^{-1}$ iff $x^{2} = 1$), and thus a (normal) subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Insightful Observation. +1!